# aiogram - при установке ошибка

Tags: python, aiogram, установка

Устанавливаю `aiogram` - вылезает следующая ошибка:

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.37.32822\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiohttp
Failed to build aiohttp
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based
```

`VisualStudio` - последняя версия

Comment: Откатите версию Python с 3.12 до 3.11. Еще не все библиотеки обновлены для новой версии Python. В данном случае не обновлены и aiogram, и его зависимость - aiohttp.